# Non Blocking File Read in PHP

Tags: php

I am implementing a script to read data from a file in php. It contains around 30 thousand lines. The problem I am facing is that it takes a lot of time for the server to read the file and echo the results and send back the page. Is there any way by which the server can send back the response after a given time, say 2 seconds.

The result should contain the part of the file which has been processed and in the next reply it should send the part in processed in next 2 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What should I try. I have written the script to read the file but none other. I need some guidance so I may write the script that is why i posted here.

Comment: You could use ajax for this to create a polling system to read the file chunkwise till it's fully read

Comment: File reading never blocks, so there's no such thing as non-blocking file reading.

Comment: [Async I/O for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.eio.php) as requested. Combining it with proper request from client side can make this rather quick.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches for this:

1. Implement a loop like in @Barmar's answer but with something that will save the current position between requests/responses.

The problem with @Barmar's approach is that it just reads the first chunk of the file and returns it. It's not clear what to do with the rest of the file. One way to improve it is to do the processing via a series of requests. For example:

- Client makes a request to `http://example.com/process?file_position=0`
- Server starts processing at position 0 then responds with the data for the first part of the file and the new file position
- Client makes another request to `http://example.com/process?file_position=1000`
- Server reads from the new position to wherever it gets in 2 seconds and replies again
- ...

2. Use a queue processing system to do the file reading in the background and use AJAX (or websockets) to send periodic updates to the client.

You can look into a queue system that will execute long-running jobs in the background and implement something like that. I'm using [Laravel](http://laravel.com) for an application and it has a nice queue system - basically, I have a worker task running on the server which just waits for jobs to be queued up, then executes them. See [these docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues) for an idea of how it works in Laravel. You may be able to roll your own using a combination of packages from [packagist](https://packagist.org/).

The problem ultimately stems from PHP's lack of multithreading support - it is not possible* to simply spawn a new process to do some reading and then return data to the client. For long-running tasks you either run into PHP's execution time limit or the user's browser sits there & spins for a long time.

> I am aware that there are techniques for doing this, but they tend to be hacks.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. None of the approaches do anything about *non blocking*.

Comment: @SOFe There's nothing in the question about non-blocking. It's in the title, but that appears to be poor wording to refer to the long time it takes to read the entire file.

Answer (score -1):

Read from the file in a loop, and end the loop when you reach the time limit.

```
$fd = fopen($filename);
$result = '';
$limit = 2;
$stop_time = time() + $limit;
$block_size = 1024;
while (time() < $stop_time) {
    $result .= fread($fd, $block_size);
    if (feof($fd)) {
        break;
    }
}
close($fd);
echo $result;
```

Comment: this is not non-block, fopen and fread are inherently  blocking.

Comment: @anru The time they take is negligible compared to the 2-second time limit.

Comment: @anru There's nothing in the question that requires non-blocking I/O. The title is poor wording for what they ask for in the question itself.